# Concentrato come un laser

Tags: word-usage, translation, adjectives

Sono alla ricerca di una traduzione valida per il termine inglese **"laser-focused"**, riferito ad una persona che è "concentrata come un laser". Ad occhio anche la traduzione letterale è comprensibile, magari esiste un modo più elegante per tradurlo.

Edit: Il contesto è riferito ad una partita di scacchi:

> "Kasparov, nonstante fosse 'concentrato come un laser', non intuì che
>   la mossa di Deep Blue era una trappola"

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Comment: “Concentratissimo”? Spesso l'inglese ha bisogno di modi alternativi per rafforzare anche perché non ha il corrispondente del nostro superlativo assoluto.

Comment: Grazie della risposta. In effetti, poiché il termine inglese è di "ultima generazione", cercavo un equivalente accostamento moderno ma non ho trovato nulla finora.

Comment: Se dovessi tradurlo io, personalmente non sentirei il bisogno di mantenere necessariamente il riferimento “moderno”, che ritengo sia accidentale. L'inglese ha molte di queste espressioni – _crystal-clear_, _rock-hard_, _dog-tired_ e così via – che sono frasi fatte: non serve necessariamente un richiamo specifico – in questi esempi, alla mineralogia o alla zoologia – anche perché il parlante inglese quasi non li percepisce esplicitamente.

Comment: Secondo me quest'uso di "laser-focused" non ha molto senso (sono madrelingua inglese). È comprensibile, di certo, ma lo definirei una maniera mediocre di descrivere la situazione. Se io fossi in te, non mi affaticherei ad escogitare una traduzione che mantenga il riferimento a un laser. "Concentratissimo" rende bene l'idea, e suggerisco anche "intensamente focalizzato".

Comment: @FrancescoMarchioni: Ho visto che hai anche [questo account](https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/4380/francesco-marchioni?tab=profile). Se volessi unificare i tuoi account, nel "Help Center" si spiega quello che devi fare: "visit the [contact form](http://italian.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’."

Answer (score 5):

Per rimanere in ambito ottico potrebbe essere valida la traduzione con il termine ***focalizzata***.

> La ricercatrice è ***focalizzata*** sul raggiungimento degli obiettivi di
>   ricerca.

Comment: Grazie mille del suggerimento.

Comment: Non capisco il voto negativo. Sarebbe auspicabile una spiegazione...